# Python lxml/beautiful soup to find all links on a web page

Tags: python, lxml

I am writing a script to read a web page, and build a database of links that matches a certain criteria.  Right now I am stuck with lxml and understanding how to grab all the `<a href>`'s from the html...

```
result = self._openurl(self.mainurl)
content = result.read()
html = lxml.html.fromstring(content)
print lxml.html.find_rel_links(html,'href')
```

Comment: this has been asked dozens of times and has good answers, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use XPath. Something like (can't test from here):

```
urls = html.xpath('//a/@href')
```

Comment: OK, then how can I get the 2 variables back from a string such as:


<li><a href="http://domain.org/blah/">Economic &amp; Name </a></li>

I need the URL, and the description

Comment: Use `html.xpath('//a')` instead and then (off the top of my head) `.attr['href']` for the url and `.text` for the contents.

Comment: where can i read more?  how do you know the fields for xpath? reading http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: This will extract `href`s from `<a>`s, only. [Iorien's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6160418/906658) is a more general.

Answer (score 5):

With [`iterlinks`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#working-with-links), lxml provides an excellent function for this task.

> This yields (element, attribute, link, pos) for every link [...] in an action, archive, background, cite, classid, codebase, data, href, longdesc, profile, src, usemap, dynsrc, or lowsrc attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I want to provide an alternative lxml-based solution.

The solution uses the function provided in lxml.cssselect

```
    import urllib
    import lxml.html
    from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
    connection = urllib.urlopen('http://www.yourTargetURL/')
    dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
    selAnchor = CSSSelector('a')
    foundElements = selAnchor(dom)
    print [e.get('href') for e in foundElements]
```

Comment: love this answer, now I can use my css/js knowledge to find elements. for others, please note you have to pip install it separately now, but then the import works as above: https://lxml.de/cssselect.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse
from lxml import html as lh
class Crawler:
     def __init__(self, start_url):
         self.start_url = start_url
         self.base_url = f'{urlparse(self.start_url).scheme}://{urlparse(self.start_url).netloc}'
         self.visited_urls = set()

     def fetch_urls(self, html):
         urls = []
         dom = lh.fromstring(html)
         for href in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
              url = urljoin(self.base_url, href)
              if url not in self.visited_urls and url.startswith(self.base_url):
                   urls.append(url)
         return urls
```