# Python: Parse all elements under a div

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse all elements under `div` using beautifulsoup the issue is that I don't know all the elements underneath the div prior to parsing. For example a div can have text data in paragraph mode and bullet format along with some `href` elements. Each url that I open can have different elements underneath the specific div class that I am looking at:

example:

url a can have following:

```
<div class='content'>
<p> Hello I have a link </p>

<li> I have a bullet point

<a href="foo.com">foo</a>
</div>
```

but url b

can have

```
<div class='content'>
<p> I only have paragraph </p>

</div>
```

I started as doing something like this:

```
content = souping_page.body.find('div', attrs={'class': 'content})
```

but how to go beyond this is little confuse. I was hoping to create one string from all the parse data as a end result.

At the end I want the following string to be obtain from each example:

Example 1: Final Output

```
 parse_data = Hello I have a link I have a bullet point 
 parse_links = foo.com
```

Example 2: Final Output

```
 parse_data = I only have paragraph
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are looking for here. Did you want to get all textual data from a tag? Then just use `tag.text`.

Comment: I want to get all the data, textual and links

Comment: What does that *mean*? Can you give us an example of the expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through child tags?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Pieters For example my SO profile has one line comparing to your SO profile where as its complex right... how about that example.

Comment: @Anov yes all the child parse it and create a one text string obviously each word separate by space.

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon: What has this got to do with our profiles? I am asking you what output you data you hoped to glean from both your samples. For example two variables, one with all text and another with all hyperlinks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry I thought giving an example to what I am trying to parse since I am parsing internal website... yes that would work one with all text and other with all hyperlinks.

Comment: @Anov I just updated the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get just the text of a text with [`element.get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample1 = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div class='content'>
... <p> Hello I have a link </p>
... 
... <li> I have a bullet point
... 
... <a href="foo.com">foo</a>
... </div>
... ''').find('div')
>>> sample2 = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div class='content'>
... <p> I only have paragraph </p>
... 
... </div>
... ''').find('div')
>>> sample1.get_text()
u'\n Hello I have a link \n I have a bullet point\n\nfoo\n'
>>> sample2.get_text()
u'\n I only have paragraph \n'
```

or you can strip it down a little using [`element.stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string-generators):

```
>>> ' '.join(sample1.stripped_strings)
u'Hello I have a link I have a bullet point foo'
>>> ' '.join(sample2.stripped_strings)
u'I only have paragraph'
```

To get all links, look for all `a` elements with `href` attributes and gather these in a list:

```
>>> [a['href'] for a in sample1.find_all('a', href=True)]
['foo.com']
>>> [a['href'] for a in sample2.find_all('a', href=True)]
[]
```

The `href=True` argument limits the search to `<a>` tags that have a `href` attribute defined.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Beautiful Soup docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children), to iterate over the children of a tag use either .contents to get them as a list or .children (a generator).

```
for child in title_tag.children:
    print(child)
```

So, in your case, for example, you grab the .text of each tag and concatenate it together. I'm not clear on whether you want the link location or simply the label, if the former, refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautiful-soup).