# BeautifulSoup: Within Webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have just installed BeautifulSoup. I can extract all the links using BS, but i can't use it to navigate WITHIN the webpage. Is there a way give the main URL and extract all the information from the links in the webpage?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You still can use `BeautifulSoup` for [extracting links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautiful-soup) from a web page. For following them, you can either stick with [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Another option, that could better fit your needs is to use [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) web-scraping framework. It has [link extracting mechanism](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) built-in:

> LinkExtractors are objects whose only purpose is to extract links from
>   web pages (scrapy.http.Response objects) which will be eventually
>   followed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found `lxml` to be more efficient, consistent to use, and even *robust* than BeautifulSoup.

In a number of cases (may related to encodings?) BeautifulSoup would fail badly with parsing some broken web pages for me. The `lxml` result was close to what web browsers see, and worked much better on these broken pages.

Extracting links is trivial with either:

BeautifulSoup:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    # Do something with a['href']
```

`lxml`:

```
 for href in doc.xpath('//a/@href'):
     # Do something with "href"
```

alternate `lxml`:

```
 for a in doc.xpath('//a'):
     # Do something with a['href']
```

Please see the documentation on how to parse the document.