# Get XPath of an element in DOM tree?

Tags: python, dom, selenium, xpath, lxml

I'm using ***lxml*** implementation in ***python*** for HTML and XML parsing.
Setting up a parser like

```
parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser()
```

and returning a tree from HTML source (string)

```
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(html, parser).getroottree() # Returns a XML tree
```

According to ***lxml*** docs, this should return a **DOM tree (XML)**

I want to find certain elements having tags such as "a", "div", "span", etc.

How can I get the **XPath** of all possible elements using their tag names?

**EDIT**:  I am actually developing a AJAX crawler, so I need Selenium to click certain elements which can change DOM state. I send the HTML source to the lxml for analysis.

For example, taking default elements in a list like

```
["a", "button", "li", "nav", "ol", "span", "ul", "header", "footer", "section"]
```

I need to get xpaths of the above elements so that I can pass them to Selenium for click, and for other event triggers.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example: input (html fragment) and the desired output? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to use a separate parser, `selenium` itself is pretty powerful in terms of [`Locating Elements`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('url_goes_here')
list_of_elements = ["a", "button", "li", "nav", "ol", "span", "ul", "header", "footer", "section"]
for tag_name in list_of_elements:
    for element in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name(tag_name):
         print element
```

Comment: But Selenium is what makes it slow. Do you know a method to do this using lxml? Thanks.

Comment: @user3623152 I think you have to stick with `selenium` since you need webdriver element instances for further actions - you said you would need to click and trigger events on the elements found.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found using "beautiful Soup" makes this sort of thing much easier.

http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html

There are already a number of similar questions here, try:

[retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautiful-soup)

Comment: Beautiful soup is too cumbersome, and doesn't parse as good and fast as lxml. This is taking into fact that I need the crawler to be high performing. Also the link you provided is just on taking *href* links from the HTML source.

Comment: My apologies, your question was updated somwhat while I was posting. I've never had performance issues with bs, but I've generally used it for off-line, after-the-fact data crunching.

Comment: Look at lxml, it is fast, really fast and good at broken HTML. If I give the crawler to spider maybe 5 targets, then BS would be a huge bottleneck. :)

Comment: Beautiful soup takes a parser argument in the constructor. I tell beautiful soup to use lxml as the parser.