# Extract src in beatifulsoup parser python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

need extract src in tag with beatifulsoup in python of tag 'div.participant-logo' .

```
import requests
import bs4

root_url = 'here url to parse'

response = requests.get(root_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

logo_cuadro1 = soup.select('div.participant-logo')

print (logo_cuadro1)
```

Code HTML

```
<td class="participant-logo"><a href="/futbol/espana/equipo-cordoba-cf-8004992.html"><img src="http://medias/logos/icons/teams-80/7869.png?v=2"></a></td>
```

Comment: Don't use `response.text`. Use `response.content`, perhaps with `response.encoding` passed in to `BeautifulSoup` as the `from_encoding` argument, provided `'charset' in response.headers.get('content-type')` is true. See [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22583436)

Comment: `logo_cuadro1 = soup.select('div.participant-logo').find("src")`

Comment: What is the actual HTML you have? What is the expected output? What do you mean by *src in tag*?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: that's not clear; perhaps the OP wanted the source of the whole tag as HTML?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, well the question is pretty unclear, a literal interpretation of the question suggests what I provided.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: which is why I voted to close it. As it stands it is unanswerable.

Comment: Hi, updated the post with the code.

Comment: @Fabián, added an answer, I presume you want the link from src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the src:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("""<td class="participant-logo"><a href="/futbol/espana/equipo-cordoba-cf-8004992.html"><img src="http://medias/logos/icons/teams-80/7869.png?v=2"></a></td>""")

logo_cuadro1 = soup.find("img")["src"]

print (logo_cuadro1)

http://medias/logos/icons/teams-80/7869.png?v=2
```

In your case:

```
sel  = soup.select('div.participant-logo')
link = sel[0].find("img")["src"]
```

Comment: Hi, this return error.
logo_cuadro1 = soup.select('div.participant-logo').find("img")["src"]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your CSS selection to the an image with `src` attribute:

```
for img in soup.select('div.participant-logo img[src]'):
    print img['src']
```