# How to print only url data from Webscraper

Tags: python, html, scraper

i'm building a webscraper and want it retrieve the url from a title.
This is the code i'm currently using :

```
for item in g_data: 
    print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"})[1]
```

And this prints:

```
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal"
 href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/Scotch-BUFF-Brown-Packaging-Parcel/dp/B001OYOI5E"
 title="3M Scotch BUFF Brown Packaging Parcel Tape 50mm x 66m - Pack of
 2"><h2 class="a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title
 a-text-normal">3M Scotch BUFF Brown Packaging Parcel Tape 50mm x 66m -
 Pack of 2</h2></a>
```

Now what I would like is to be able to just get

```
"http://www.amazon.co.uk/Scotch-BUFF-Brown-Packaging-Parcel/dp/B001OYOI5E"
```

, however i'm not sure how to target that specific data.
Does anyone know how to do this?, I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Although similar to the other post, this is different and is not as complex, I think the solution in the other problem could work, but would require rewriting of code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Comment: which libraries are you using @jamie

Comment: I'm using requests and beautiful soup.

Comment: @AnishShah I'm using requests and beautiful soup.

Comment: @snicksie I looked at that, and although it is similar, I don't know how I can use that in my code.

Comment: try this: ```print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"})[1]['href']``` (so get the href of the anchor-element, which contains the url you want)

Comment: @snicksie That worked, and it was so simple, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the entire anchor-element, you only need the value of the href-attribute. You can access this attribute as following:

```
for item in g_data: 
    print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"})[1]['href']
```