# Python crawler: downloading HTML page

Tags: python, html, web-crawler, python-requests

I want to crawl (gently) a website and download each HTML page that I crawl. To accomplish that I use the library requests. I already did my crawl-listing and I try to crawl them using urllib.open but without user-agent, I get an error message. So I choose to use requests, but I don't really know how to use it.

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1'
}
page = requests.get('http://www.xf.com/ranking/get/?Amount=1&From=left&To=right', headers=headers)
with open('pages/test.html', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write(page.text)
```

The problem is when the script try to write the response in my file I get some encoding error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6673-6675: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can we write in a file without having those encoding problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, text files don't accept Unicode strings. Use the `response.content` to access the original binary, undecoded content:

```
with open('pages/test.html', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(page.content)
```

This will write the downloaded HTML in the original encoding as served by the website.

Alternatively, if you want to re-encode all responses to a specific encoding, use `io.open()` to produce a file object that does accept Unicode:

```
import io

with io.open('pages/test.html', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    outfile.write(page.text)
```

Note that many websites rely on signalling the correct codec in the *HTML tags*, and the content can be served without a characterset parameter altogether.

In that case `requests` uses the *default* codec for the `text/*` mimetype, Latin-1, to decode HTML to Unicode text. **This is often the wrong codec** and relying on this behaviour can lead to [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) output later on. I recommend you stick to writing the binary content and rely on tools like BeautifulSoup to detect the correct encoding later on.

Alternatively, test explicitly for the `charset` parameter being present and only re-encode (via `response.text` and `io.open()` or otherwise) if `requests` did not fall back to the Latin-1 default. See *[retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup/22583436#22583436)* for an answer where I use such a method to tell BeautifulSoup what codec to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile.write(page.text.encode('utf8', 'replace'))
```

I found the documentation right here: [unicode problem](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html)

Comment: The UTF-8 codec can encode all of the Unicode standard, the `'replace'` error handler is redundant here as it'll never be needed.