# Unable to find all links with BeautifulSoup to extract links from a website (Link identification)

Tags: python-2.7, hyperlink, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I’m using this code found here ( [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup?noredirect=1&lq=1)) to extract all links from a website using.

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.bestwestern.com.au')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print link['href']
```

I’m using this site http://www.bestwestern.com.au  as test.
Unfortunately, I notice that the code is not extracting some links for example this one http://www.bestwestern.com.au/about-us/careers/ . I don’t know why. 
In the code of the page this is what I found.

```
<li><a href="http://www.bestwestern.com.au/about-us/careers/">Careers</a></li>
```

I think the extractor should normally identify it. 
On the BeautifulSoup documentation I can read:  “The most common type of unexpected behavior is that you can’t find a tag that you know is in the document. You saw it going in, but find_all() returns [] or find() returns None. This is another common problem with Python’s built-in HTML parser, which sometimes skips tags it doesn’t understand. Again, the solution is to install lxml or html5lib.” 
So I installed html5lib. But I still have the same behavior.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't actually see "Careers" link on this page - are we looking onto the same page?..

Comment: You'll see the "careers" link by looking the sitemap here http://www.bestwestern.com.au/sitemap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is - you are using `BeautifulSoup` version 3 which is not being maintained anymore. You need to upgrade to [`BeautifulSoup` version 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Another problem is that there is no "careers" link on the main page, but there is one on the "sitemap" page - request it and parse with the default `html.parser`  parser - you'll see "careers" link printed among others:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

response = requests.get('http://www.bestwestern.com.au/sitemap/')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True)):
    print(link['href'])
```

Note how I've moved the "has to have href" rule to the soup strainer.

Comment: I have the version 4 of BeautifulSoup but still can't find the link.  I don't know if the default parser as Python’s built-in HTML parser, but I think the problem may come from that side.

Comment: This is another common problem with Python’s built-in HTML parser, which sometimes skips tags it doesn’t understand. Again, the solution is to install lxml or html5lib.” So I installed html5lib. But I still have the same behavior.

Comment: @BND nono, as I've asked - there is no "careers" link on the main page, but there is one on the `sitemap` page - updated the code in the answer - works for me as is and prints the "carrers" link as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works for me too. But I don't really understand. Why the link can't be found from the main page http://www.bestwestern.com.au ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works for me too. But I understand now. The code only extract links on the page not on all the website ? I'm looking for something to do the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so this is a old question but I stumbled upon it in my search and it seems like it should be relatively simple to accomplish. I did switch from httplib2 to requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
baseurl = 'http://www.bestwestern.com.au'

SEEN_URLS = []
def get_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    for link in BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True)):
        print(link['href'])
        SEEN_URLS.append(link['href'])
        if baseurl in link['href'] and link['href'] not in SEEN_URLS:
            get_links(link['href'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(baseurl)
```