# Arabic encoding error when using requests restful client

Tags: java, python, rest, character-encoding, python-2.6

I have the following restful client in python:

```
import requests;
s= 'وإليك ما يقوله إثنان من هؤلاء';
resp = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/MyApp/webresources/production/sendSentence', json={'sentence': s,} )
```

the aforementionned code call a web service implemented in java which returns the same sentence sent from the requests client.

this is the java webservice:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("text/html; charset=UTF-8")
@Path("/sendSentence")
public String sendSentence(@Context HttpServletRequest requestContext, String valentryJson) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (valentryJson != null) {
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(valentryJson);
            String sentence = jsonObject.getString("sentence");

            return sentence;
        }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
    }
    return "";
}
```

the problem is the encoding because when i try to print the content this is the result:

```
>>> resp.content

'\xd9\x88\xd8\xa5\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x83 \xd9\x85\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x8a\xd9\x82\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x87 \xd8\xa5\xd8\xab\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86 \xd9\x85\xd9\x86 \xd9\x87\xd8\xa4\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa1'
```

Or when  I use  print:

```
>>> print resp.content

    ظˆط¥ظ„ظٹظƒ ظ…ط§ ظٹظ‚ظˆظ„ظ‡ ط¥ط«ظ†ط§ظ† ظ…ظ† ظ‡ط¤ظ„ط§ط،
```

Comment: You didn't decode the content. Presumably this is Python 2?

Comment: I have tried to decode it using resp.content.decode('utf8') it does not work

Comment: yes, it is python 2.6.5

Comment: **How** does that not work? Do you get a `UnicodeEncodeError` when you print the result to the console? If so, then your console can't handle your text (Python has to encode to print, and your console is not configured to receive Arabic text).

Comment: Note that your first example would *fail* in Python 2.6, unless you used a hack to change the built-in default codec used for implicit decoding and encoding. Don't do that, that hack was disabled for a reason.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake resp.content.decode('utf8') now works. I think I have tried something else. This is why I thought it doesn not work. Thanks @MartijnPieters again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java webservice produces HTML, UTF-8 encoded:

```
@Produces("text/html; charset=UTF-8")
```

but you took the raw bytes returned without decoding:

```
>>> resp.content
```

`response.content` gives you bytes, not Unicode text. You could use the `resp.text` attribute instead, which uses the `charset` parameter of the `Content-Type` header to decode your data:

```
>>> resp.text
u'\u0648\u0625\u0644\u064a\u0643 \u0645\u0627 \u064a\u0642\u0648\u0644\u0647 \u0625\u062b\u0646\u0627\u0646 \u0645\u0646 \u0647\u0624\u0644\u0627\u0621'
>>> print resp.text
وإليك ما يقوله إثنان من هؤلاء
```

Be careful however; if *no* `charset` parameter is present, but the content-type header indicates this is a `text/...` content type (like `text/html`), then `requests` will follow the HTTP RFCs and decode the data as Latin-1. This'll silently work but may not be the correct codec. For HTML data, use a HTML parser instead, pass in the bytestring, and leave it to the parser to extract what codec is correct (HTML often records the right encoding in a `<meta>` tag). See [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup/22583436#22583436).