# How to extract links from HTML (with python)

Tags: python, html, parsing

so I've downloaded the HTML of a web page. I'm supposed to extract all of the links from the HTML and output them. Here is my code

```
f = open('html.py','r')
heb = f.readlines()
arry = []
if 'href' in heb:
    arry = arry.append(href)

    print(arry)
```

I'm trying to make a list of the links and output it, but honestly I'm pretty lost. Can someone point me in the right direction? I was thinking regex probably is the way to go
thanks

Comment: Don't use regex on html!  Use an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Beautiful Soup (which you'll need to install, e.g. with `pip install BeautifulSoup4`):

```
import bs4

with open("my-file.html") as f:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f)

links = [link['href'] for link in soup('a') if 'href' in link.attrs]
```