# Getting a URL from hyperlinks using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I scraped a webpage using BeautifulSoup, assigned to 'soup'. I can get the text 'Aberdeen' by just adding .text onto the end of 'site_url'.

What I really want to get is the complete url in a string, e.g.  "http://www.somewebsite.com/networks/site-info?site_id=ABD"

```
>>>site_link = soup.find_all('a', string='Aberdeen')[0]
>>>site_row = site_link.findParent('td').findParent('tr')
>>>site_column = site_row.findAll('td')
>>>site_url = site_column[0].contents[0]
>>>print(site_url)

<a href="../networks/site-info?site_id=ABD">Aberdeen</a>
```

I have not had any luck so far and do not know what else to try. How can I get the url?

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080472/7654934). Hope this helps!

Comment: The page I am trying to scrape is https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/latest/currentlevels and I am interested in the urls corresponding to the site names in the first columns of the table e.g. https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=ACTH for the first name which is Auchencorth Moss

Comment: @N.Ivanov I have tried something similar but the problem is that there are many different types of links on the page, I just want the said links

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to get the links the use urljoin to get the correct URLs.

```
import requests
import re

try:
    from urlparse import urljoin  # Python2
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin  # Python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= 'https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/latest/currentlevels'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Not blank'})
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for elem in soup('a', href=re.compile(r'site_id')):
    print (elem.text)
    print (urljoin(url,elem['href']))
```

Outputs:

```
Auchencorth Moss
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=ACTH
Bush Estate
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=BUSH
Dumbarton Roadside
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=DUMB
Edinburgh St Leonards
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=ED3
Glasgow Great Western Road
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=GGWR
Glasgow High Street
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=GHSR
...
```

If you just want Aberdeen use:

```
for elem in soup('a',href=re.compile(r'site_id'), string='Aberdeen'):
```

instead of:

```
for elem in soup('a', href=re.compile(r'site_id')):
```

Outputs:

```
Aberdeen
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=ABD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope it will meet all your requirements:

```
import requests ; from lxml import html

base_link = "https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk"
response = requests.get("https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/latest/currentlevels", headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}).text
tree = html.fromstring(response)
for title in tree.cssselect("table.current_levels_table td a:not(.smalltext)"):
    print(base_link + title.attrib['href'][2:])
```

Partial results:

```
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=ACTH
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=BUSH
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=DUMB
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=ED3
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=GGWR
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=GHSR
https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/networks/site-info?site_id=GLA4
```