# How to gather all links from a webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to gather links from "View More Campaigns" using Python 3? I wish to gather all 260604 links from this page?
https://www.gofundme.com/mvc.php?route=category&term=sport

Comment: *always* use a generic [python] tag, if only to get more eyeballs on the question

Answer (score 2):

When clicking on the `View More Campaigns` button, the browser requests the following URL:

```
https://www.gofundme.com/mvc.php?route=category/loadMoreTiles&page=2&term=sport&country=GB&initialTerm=
```

This could be used to request further pages as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import requests

page = 1
links = set()
length = 0

while True:
    print("Page {}".format(page))
    gofundme = requests.get('https://www.gofundme.com/mvc.php?route=category/loadMoreTiles&page={}&term=sport&country=GB&initialTerm='.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(gofundme.content, "html.parser")
    links.update([a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)])

    # Stop when no new links are found
    if len(links) == length:
        break

    length = len(links)
    page += 1

for link in sorted(links):
    print(link)
```

Giving you an output starting like:

```
https://www.gofundme.com/100-round-kumite-rundraiser
https://www.gofundme.com/10k-challenge-for-disabled-sports
https://www.gofundme.com/1yeti0
https://www.gofundme.com/2-marathons-1-month
https://www.gofundme.com/23yq67t4
https://www.gofundme.com/2fwyuwvg
```

Some of the links returned are duplicates, so a `set` is used to avoid this.
The script continues to attempt to request new pages until no new links are seen, which appears to happen at around 18 pages.

Answer (score 1):

From [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

> ```
> import httplib2
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
>
> http = httplib2.Http()
> status, response = http.request('https://www.gofundme.com/mvc.php?route=category&term=sport')
>
> for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
>     if link.has_attr('href'):
>         print (link['href'])
> ```

Comment: This won't gather all the fundraising campaign links the OP wants, only the campaigns that are initially on the page.