# Using Beautiful Soup in a class that contains spaces

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python with Beautiful Soup to scrap a list of 20 games from Steam (http://store.steampowered.com/tags/en-us/RPG/). But those games are separated not with `div`, but with an `a` tag instead. Therefore, I tried to do the following:

```
all_games=soup.find_all('a',{'class':'tab_item   app_impression_tracked'})
```

(Those blank spaces exist in Steam's HTML)

However, it returned an empty list instead of all `a` tags that contained a 'class' called `tab_item   app_impression_tracked`

I'm not trying to scrap only the game's names, but also its price, discount... And I'm not interested in the link too. I just want to grab the `a` tag because it contains all the information that I need about the games separately.

Is there a solution?

**Solution:**

`all_games = soup.find('div', {'id':'NewReleasesRows'}).find_all('a', {'class':'tab_item'})`

Those spaces were problematic, the real name of the class is `tab_item` and not `tab_item   app_impression_tracked` as I thought.

Comment: A similar question was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080472/6158987

Comment: You want just the names of the games?

Answer (score 1):

You can find needed items using css-rules in `soup.select()` method also.
Next code select 20 items from page:

```
all_games = soup.select("a.tab_item[class*='app_impression_tracked']")
```

When classes in the tag attribute `class` are separated by spaces you can match them this way: `"a.tab_item.app_impression_tracked"`. But this rule match `a` exact with these two classes and no others inside. It looks like 20 items of the list have few different `classes`.
The `*=` in brackets means `contains next string`.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue and managed to fix it by doing the

```
className = 'tab_item   app_impression_tracked'
all_games = soup.find_all('a', {'class': className.split() if '  ' in className else className})
```

So, in if class name there's more than two spaces, we split(by space, so `className` becomes `['tab_item', 'app_impression_tracked']`) the className to get the element.