# How to get url from a string in python

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm fetching webpages with the use of curl and storing it in a variable in python.

```
var = '<body><img src=\"https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg\" style=\"display: none;\"/><div class=\"wrapper\">'
```

I just want the links from the string for example:

```
"https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg"
```

I Tried matching with regular expressions by defining the start of regular expression as "(https|http) and end as ":

```
x = re.findall(r'"(https|http)*"$', var)
print(x)
```

But I'm not getting the output. Please help me with this, thanks in advance.

```
>>>[]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup

Comment: Note: There will not be only one url in the string, the curl may fetch multiple urls in string.

Comment: maybe the modules request and or BeautifulSoup are something for you. They can do quite easy what you want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5710637

Comment: do you need ALL of the links? even the ones which refer to stylesheets, javascripts, external links (be it starting with `//` and `http(s)://' ) and internal links (absolute with `/path/to` and relative with `path/to`) alike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Manoj**, you can also retrieve the value of `src` attribute  using the `split()` method multiple times as follows.

» Using lambda function (1 line statement)

```
var = '<body><img src=\"https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg\" style=\"display: none;\"/><div class=\"wrapper\">'

get_url = lambda html: html.split('=')[1].split('\"')[1]
print(get_url(var))
```

» Output

```
https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg
```

Let's expand the above approach in multiple statements to understand the actual direct process.

```
var = '<body><img src=\"https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg\" style=\"display: none;\"/><div class=\"wrapper\">'
print(var, "\n")
# <body><img src="https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg" style="display: none;"/><div class="wrapper">

parts1 = var.split("=")
print(parts1, "\n")
# ['<body><img src', '"https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg" style', '"display: none;"/><div class', '"wrapper">']

parts2 = parts1[1].split('\"')
print(parts2, "\n")
# ['', 'https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg', ' style']

print(parts2[1])
# https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg
```

» Output

```
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\Temp>python GetUrls.py
<body><img src="https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg" style="display: none;"/><div class="wrapper">

['<body><img src', '"https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg" style', '"display: none;"/><div class', '"wrapper">']

['', 'https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg', ' style']



https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.search`

```
import re
var = '<body><img src=\"https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg\" style=\"display: none;\"/><div class=\"wrapper\">'
m = re.search("src=\"(?P<url>.*?)\"", var)
if m:
    print m.group('url')
```

**Output:**

```
https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you, but the beginning may not be "src=\", it may be anything like "href=\" the pattern won't work in such cases, right?

Comment: In that case use `m = re.search("(src|href)=\"(?P<url>.*?)\"", var)`

Answer (score 0):

Using beautifulsoup you could search for `a` or `img` and check for the attributes:

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

var = '<body><a href=\"https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg\"><img src=\"https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/06/Gaming sloop, preview group, hardware _mediump.jpg\" style=\"display: none;\"/></a><div class=\"wrapper\">'
page_soup = soup(var, "html.parser")

links = []

for elm in page_soup.findAll(['a', 'img']):
    if elm.has_attr('href'):
        links.append(elm.get('href'))
    if elm.has_attr('src'):
        links.append(elm.get('src'))

print(links)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RGDE64419)