# Python If String Contains in href

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is my python code.

```
r = requests.get("myurl")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
texttmp = ""
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    image = link.get("href")
    if ".jpg" in image:
        print(image)
```

When I try to run this code, I am getting below error. How can I fix this?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-618698d3a2d7> in <module>()
     11 for link in soup.find_all('a'):
     12     image = link.get("href")
---> 13     if ".jpg" in image:
     14         print(image)
     15 

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Apparently `link.get('href') is None`. We'd need more information to tell you exactly why.

Answer (score 4):

What it's telling you is that no `href` string could be found. Hence, you need to check for `None` before you see if the `".jpg"` is in the image tag:

```
 if image and ".jpg" in image:
```

However, that's not the only thing going on. You're also trying to `get` from the found link nodes. You should check that the `a` has an attribute of `href` (some don't, see Bootstrap for examples!):

```
 for link in soup.find_all('a'):
   if link.has_attr('href'):
     #rest of code
```

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1080411/178060) and others like it (I should have googled first, too.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to representing links to other resources, html anchor tags `<a ...>` can also act as a named marker for a location in a document, so-called name tags `<a name=whatever>`, allowing the marked location to be the target of a link that uses a fragment in the URL `http://example.com/#whatever`

This is probably what you have run into, since name tags won't have href's to indicate a resource that they point to.

You'll need to check if the href returns None and skip that returned tag if it doesn't.

Good luck.