# Python Beautifulsoup getting the hyperlink

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/yyyyy.html" title="yyyyy">yyyyyy</a></li>
```

I am trying to **scrape** the data and was able to do using the beautifulsoup.

code I am using is :

```
for ul in soup.findAll('div'):
    print(ul.text)
    for li in ul.findAll('li'):
        print(li.text)
        f.write("li   "+str(li.text))
```

How can I get the href.
I am looking output as:
yyyyy;https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/yyyyy.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try [`Tag.find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find):

```
f.write("li   "+li.find('a')['href'])
```

Comment: Thank you I tried on this  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_tourist_attractions but not getting the href am I missinganythibg ..

Comment: check your `HTML` contents, why are you searching for `<div>` tags? there are no `<div>` tags in the `HTML` code..

Comment: Otherwise, I'm not sure why you don't get the `'href'`, try demo here, click `'Run'` on top of page: http://repl.it/@downshift/FlippantLeadingIntranet -- Afterwards, the `'href.txt'` file will contain `li   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_tourist_attractions`

Comment: I tried on the wiki link the same logic . its not working/.

Comment: what do you mean it is not working? did you run the demo and see the output?

Comment: Its not printing all the hrefs and text

Comment: do you want to save the href and text to the file? or just print it?

Comment: I am ok either way. to start with I want to print, issue I am having is wikipedia links

Comment: Where you are stuck .. what is the issue you are having with the wikipedia link? Your code is incomplete and you should show us where the issue is