# How to Loop and Save Data from Each Iteration

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn how to scrape data from a webpage in python and am running into trouble with how to structure my nested loops in python. I received some assistance in how I was scraping with this question ([How to pull links from within an 'a' tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106281/how-to-pull-links-from-within-an-a-tag/58106566#58106566)). I am trying to have that code essentially iterate through different weeks (and eventually years) of webpages. What I have currently is below, but it is not iterating through the two weeks I would like it to and saving it off.

```
import requests, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
weeks=['1','2']
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Teams','Link'])

scripts_head = soup.find('head').find_all('script')
all_links = {}
for i in weeks:
    r = requests.get(r'https://www.espn.com/college-football/scoreboard/_/year/2018/seasontype/2/week/'+i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for script in scripts_head:
        if 'window.espn.scoreboardData' in script.text:
            json_scoreboard = json.loads(re.search(r'({.*?});', script.text).group(1))
            for event in json_scoreboard['events']:
                name = event['name']
                for link in event['links']:
                    if link['text'] == 'Gamecast':
                        gamecast = link['href']
                all_links[name] = gamecast
                #Save data to dataframe
                data2=pd.DataFrame(list(all_links.items()),columns=['Teams','Link'])
        #Append new data to existing data        
        data=data.append(data2,ignore_index = True)


#Save dataframe with all links to csv for future use
data.to_csv(r'game_id_data.csv')
```

Edit: So to add some clarification, it is creating duplicates of the data from one week and repeatedly appending it to the end. I also edited the code to include the proper libraries, it should be able to be copy and pasted and run in python.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
"It is not working" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Please see the edited question and let me know if there is still an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the workaround I came up with is below, I am still getting duplicate game ID's in my final dataset, but at least I am looping through the entire desired set and getting all of them. Then at the end I dedupe.

```
import requests, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

years=['2015','2016','2017','2018']
weeks=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14']
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Teams','Link'])

all_links = {}
for year in years:
    for i in weeks:
        r = requests.get(r'https://www.espn.com/college-football/scoreboard/_/year/'+ year + '/seasontype/2/week/'+i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        scripts_head = soup.find('head').find_all('script')
        for script in scripts_head:
            if 'window.espn.scoreboardData' in script.text:
                json_scoreboard = json.loads(re.search(r'({.*?});', script.text).group(1))
                for event in json_scoreboard['events']:
                    name = event['name']
                    for link in event['links']:
                        if link['text'] == 'Gamecast':
                            gamecast = link['href']
                    all_links[name] = gamecast
                #Save data to dataframe
                data2=pd.DataFrame(list(all_links.items()),columns=['Teams','Link'])
                #Append new data to existing data        
                data=data.append(data2,ignore_index = True)


#Save dataframe with all links to csv for future use
data_test=data.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
data_test.to_csv(r'all_years_deduped.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your loop logic:

```
    if 'window.espn.scoreboardData' in script.text:
        ...
            data2=pd.DataFrame(list(all_links.items()),columns=['Teams','Link'])
    #Append new data to existing data        
    data=data.append(data2,ignore_index = True)
```

Your indentation on the last line is wrong.  As given, you append `data2` regardless of whether you have new scoreboard data.  When you don't, you skip the `if` body and simply append the previous `data2` value.

Comment: So I've tried that last line at all possible indentations, none of which seems to return correctly. Are you saying I need to add in logic deleting the previous run before the next iteration?

Comment: No, just that the immediate problem is to put that `append` command *under* the `if` rather than afterward.  If you have further problems, please post a new question or update the existing one as suggested in the MCVE description.