# Unable to get eBay links from each listing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am unable to attain each eBay listing's link. I searched all over Google/StackOverflow and found a solution which is to use this "link = items.findAll('a', href=True)". Unfortunately, it does not work for me since this is what I [get in return.](https://pastebin.com/8UKQE9UY) I only want the ebay links.

```py
for items in bs.findAll('li', {'class': 's-item'}):
    links = bs.find_all('a', href=True)
    print(links)
```

[What I want my code to return.](https://pastebin.com/9LebY7be)

My Entire code: https://pastebin.com/uNd1th8Z

Thank you so much. Seriously.

Comment: You don't get links, but elements that got the tag <a> and attribute href (so links). In order to get this URL, you need to access this field with the dot notation (so access one of this elements and do element['href'])

Comment: Furthermore there is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Crissal has given you a good reference, and I tested scraping from your url myself. The tricky part is to get the relevant hrefs (there are many irrelevant hrefs), if you are stuck you may refer to my code.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('(your_path_here)/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=watches&_sacat=0&_pgn=1')
bs = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))

#this is the one liner to get your relevant hrefs, those with class='s-item__link'
ls = [l['href'] for l in bs if (l.has_attr('data-track')&l.has_attr('href')&l.has_attr('class')) if l['class'][0]=='s-item__link']

#print or save to a text file
#print(ls)

#with open('links.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
#    outfile.write('\n'.join(ls))
```

Output from print

```
https://www.ebay.com/itm/SKMEI-Watch-Mens-Womens-Watches-Waterproof-Sport-Outdoor-LED-Digital-Wristwatch/392260574708?hash=item5b548d5df4:m:myDW5IBI631t2UBz65C2Ztw
https://www.ebay.com/itm/LED-Watches-Men-Women-Sport-Casual-Digital-Army-Military-Silicone-Wrist-Watch/193040878143?hash=item2cf2220a3f:m:m7VH5iopUucVEYPr9y5dfxA
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Men-Women-Leather-Strap-Line-Analog-Quartz-Ladies-Wrist-Watches-Fashion-Watch/202788343863?hash=item2f37209037:m:mOWAjJgHKIYzv8YqDPxLZqA
.
.
.
```