# How to get links to all articles on a website?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

HI I am really new to BS4 or selenium. I was wondering if there is a way to get links to all articles on a website.

For instance https://uk.yahoo.com will have many news articles. how can I (or is it possible to) get the list of links to all those articles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Add your own user agent string.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get(url='https://uk.yahoo.com ', headers={'User-Agent':''})
soup = BeatifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parse')

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile('^https://')}
    links.append(link.get('href'))
print(links)
```