# Select a specific URL with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following soup

```
 </title>
  <meta content="Erfahre aus erster Hand, ob xxx als Arbeitgeber zu dir passt. 21 Erfahrungsberichte von Mitarbeitern liefern dir die Antwort." name="description"/>
  <link href="https://www.kununu.com/de/xxx/kommentare/3" rel="next"/>
  <link href="https://www.kununu.com/de/xxx/kommentare" rel="prev"/>
  <link href="https://www.kununu.com/de/xxx/kommentare/2" rel="canonical"/>
  <script type="application/ld+json">
```

I would like to select the URL with the attribute "next"

```
<link href="https://www.kununu.com/de/xxx/kommentare/3" rel="next"/>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Your question was answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.findAll("link", {"rel" : "next"})

for result in results:
   if result.has_attr('href'):
      print(link['href'])
```