# Python, Beautifullsoup - get href link

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have question, I try to download links from the site and it returns None. I don't know what I'm doing wrong ... Can someone please help me ?? THX...

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    
page = "https://mojmikolow.pl/informacje,0.html"
page = requests.get(page).content
data_entries = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all("section", {"class": "news"})

for data_entrie in data_entries:    
    get_link = data_entrie.get('href')
    print(get_link)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pull out the anchor tag `<a>` that contains the href:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = "https://mojmikolow.pl/informacje,0.html"
page = requests.get(page).content
data_entries = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all("section", {"class": "news"})
    
for data_entrie in data_entries:    
    link_tag = data_entrie.find('a',href=True)
    get_link = link_tag.get('href')
    print(get_link)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`soup.find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) to extract all the [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) (link) tags, and then get the value of the `href` attribute from each of them:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

page = "https://mojmikolow.pl/informacje,0.html"
page = requests.get(page).content
data_entries = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all("section", {"class": "news"})

for data_entry in data_entries:    
    links = data_entry.find_all("a", href=True)
    for link in links:
        print(link["href"])
```