# how to extract link from html file.(I am using python)

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

At first sorry for my bad English.

i am trying to **scrape** web information by python.

this is the code from html, i'd like to extract only link, except the text next to link.

`<a href="https://www.mk.co.kr/news/culture/view/2021/03/258551/"">abcdefg~blahblahblah</a>`

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap. Scrap means ‘rubbish’.

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question with your code details so it's a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

There is a question about this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)
Also i found this blog post [here](https://pythonspot.com/extract-links-from-webpage-beautifulsoup/)

Answer (score 0):

Using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html), you could [locate element by xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//meta[@name="url"]/@content')
```