# Extract all hyperlink using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to extract all the hyperlink from an internal sharepoint website using beautiful soup in python but whenever I'm trying to run the program I'm getting zero results. When I checked the view source of the website it also doesn't show any hyperlink. However I can see all the link using the inspect option in the browser. is there any way I can extract all those links using python.

**Code:**

```
def main():

    r=requests.get('https://abc[.]com/query?',auth=HttpNtlmAuth(spuser,getpass.getpass()))
print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('div',{'class':"list_episode"}):    
    print(link)
```

The above code provide no results.

Comment: You'll need to give us a sample of the code on the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

> When I checked the view source of the website it also
> doesn't show any hyperlink.

The site may be using Javascript to dynamically fill in the links.

If so, you will likely need a browser to run the Javascript before you parse the links.

Selenium is a tool that you can run from Python to access the links.  See: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io

Comment: is there any way I can do it without Selenium ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests

url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = Soup(page, "lxml")

links = [link.get('href') for link in soup.findAll('a')]
```

If this does not work, then submit another question with your source code and exact error

Comment: Instead of `findAll()` syntax better use `find_all()`

Comment: Yes. `find_all()` is the newer python3 convention.