# how to get specific links with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl HTML source with Python using BeautifulSoup.
I need to get the href of specific link `<a>` tags.

This is my test code. I want to get links `<a href="/example/test/link/`**activity1~10**`"target="_blank">`

```html
<div class="listArea">
   <div class="activity_sticky" id="activity">
   .
   .
   </div>
   <div class="activity_content activity_loaded">
      <div class="activity-list-item activity_item__1fhpg">
         <div class="activity-list-item_activity__3FmEX">
            <div>...</div>
            <a href="/example/test/link/activity1" target="_blank">
               <div class="activity-list-item_addr">
                  <span> 0x1292311</span>
               </div>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="activity-list-item activity_item__1fhpg">
         <div class="activity-list-item_activity__3FmEX">
            <div>...</div>
            <a href="/example/test/link/activity2" target="_blank">
               <div class="activity-list-item_addr">
                  <span> 0x1292312</span>
               </div>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      .
      .
      .
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  The BeautifulSoup documentation has many examples, including this situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 2):

Check the [main page of the bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code for the problem. You should find the all `<a></a>`, then to getting the value of href.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('a'):
    if i['target'] == "_blank":
        print(i['href'])
```

Hope my answer could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Select the `<a>` specific - lternative to @Mason Ma answer you can also use `css selectors`:

```
soup.select('.activity_content a')]
```

or by its attribute `target` -

```
soup.select('.activity_content a[target="_blank"]')
```

#### Example

Will give you a list of links, matching your condition:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="activity_content activity_loaded">
      <div class="activity-list-item activity_item__1fhpg">
         <div class="activity-list-item_activity__3FmEX">
            <div>...</div>
            <a href="/example/test/link/activity1" target="_blank">
               <div class="activity-list-item_addr">
                  <span> 0x1292311</span>
               </div>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="activity-list-item activity_item__1fhpg">
         <div class="activity-list-item_activity__3FmEX">
            <div>...</div>
            <a href="/example/test/link/activity2" target="_blank">
               <div class="activity-list-item_addr">
                  <span> 0x1292312</span>
               </div>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[x['href'] for x in soup.select('.activity_content a[target="_blank"]')]
```

#### Output

```
['/example/test/link/activity1', '/example/test/link/activity2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, you're trying to extract the links (href) from anchor tags where the target value is _blank. You can do this by searching for all anchor tags then narrowing down to those whose target == '_blank'

```
links = soup.findAll('a', attrs = {'target' : '_blank'})
for link in links:
    print(link.get('href'))
```