# How to get all links from a webpage using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape a site using Python, Selenium, Beautifulsoup.
When I tried to get all the links ,It' returning an invalid string.
This is what I have tried
Can someone help me please?

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.hirist.com/c/filter/mobile-applications-jobs-in-cochin%20kochi_trivandrum%20thiruvananthapuram-5-70_75-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-2.html?ref=homepagecat')
sleep(10)
links = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='.//div[@class="jobfeed-wrapper multiple-wrapper"]')
for link in links:
    link.get_attribute('href')
    print(link)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your selection with `xpath`, you select the `<div>` that do not have an `href` attribute. Select also its first `<a>` like `.//div[@class="jobfeed-wrapper multiple-wrapper"]/a` and it will work:

```
links = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='.//div[@class="jobfeed-wrapper multiple-wrapper"]/a')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

##### Example

Instead of `time` use `WebDriverWait` to check if specific elements are available.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.hirist.com/c/filter/mobile-applications-jobs-in-cochin%20kochi_trivandrum%20thiruvananthapuram-5-70_75-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-2.html?ref=homepagecat'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/div[@class="jobfeed-wrapper multiple-wrapper"]/a')))
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

##### Output

```
https://www.hirist.com/j/xforia-technologies-android-developer-javakotlin-10-15-yrs-1011605.html?ref=cl&jobpos=1&jobversion=2
https://www.hirist.com/j/firminiq-system-ios-developer-swiftobjective-c-3-10-yrs-1011762.html?ref=cl&jobpos=2&jobversion=2
https://www.hirist.com/j/firminiq-system-android-developer-kotlin-3-10-yrs-1011761.html?ref=cl&jobpos=3&jobversion=2
https://www.hirist.com/j/react-native-developer-mobile-app-designing-3-5-yrs-1009438.html?ref=cl&jobpos=4&jobversion=2
https://www.hirist.com/j/flutter-developer-iosandroid-apps-2-3-yrs-1008214.html?ref=cl&jobpos=5&jobversion=2
https://www.hirist.com/j/accubits-technologies-react-native-developer-ios-android-platforms-3-7-yrs-1003520.html?ref=cl&jobpos=6&jobversion=2
https://www.hirist.com/j/appincubator-react-native-developer-iosandroid-platform-2-7-yrs-1001957.html?ref=cl&jobpos=7&jobversion=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare path to chromedriver on your computer. Check where the chromdriver is, then try

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
```

Comment: my ChromeDriver is working fine. Only problem is not getting links